# AngularJS ng-show dynamic not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one problem. I just defind my edit form in ng-repeat when click button 'Edit' with object

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in accountLst">
    <td ng-hide="edit{{account.accountName}}">
      {{account.fullName}}
    </td>
    <td ng-show="edit{{account.accountName}}">
      I want to show this line and hidden other!
    </td>
    <td ng-hide="edit{{account.accountName}}">
      {{account.accountName}}
    </td>
    <td ng-hide="edit{{account.accountName}}">
      {{account.email}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="editaccount(account)">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my editaccount function

```
$scope.editaccount = function (obj) {
    var res = false;
    var tmp = 'edit'.concat(obj.accountName);
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.accountLst.length; i++) {
      if(angular.equals(obj.accountName, $scope.accountLst[i].accountName)) {
        res = true;
        break;
      } else if(!angular.equals(obj.accountName, $scope.accountLst[i].accountName)){
        res = false;
      }
    }
    //$scope.edit123 = true;
    $scope.$tmp = res;
    console.log(tmp + ' is ' + $scope.$tmp);
    return res;
}
```

Everything work fine except: 
Example, 
I input accountName = '123', then 
If I define $scope.edit123 = true; => it work,
If through $scope.$tmp = true; => not work anymore? (tmp = edit123 too);

Please help me - I'm newbie.
Here is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/otp3ooyd/3/

Comment: You've got errors in that js fiddler...plus a string value doesn't evaluate to falsy/trusy...

Comment: @Rain. i have a doubt in your code validation. i think it should be OR (||) condition every where in place of AND (&&)   -  <button 
 ng-disabled="accountForm.fullName.$pristine && accountForm.fullName.$invalid || accountForm.repassword.$error.isMatch"
 ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

Comment: @Leo I know, Just combine in one file and it will be work fine!

Comment: @MukulSharma this button work fine for me (until now - I'm just testing, not finish yet). I'm asking for another problem. Tks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the semi-colon after $scope.$tmp = true.

I have confirmed the same in you jsfiddle code.

Comment: I tried do anything as I can but still same problem. This mistake just happen when I copied my code.

Answer (score 0):

try out in thus way it may work.

var tmp = "edit123"
$scope[tmp]= true

Comment: Please see my full code, edit123 just is my test when accountName='123'